# How to cancel mobclix full screen ad in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, mobclix

I am developing an android application in which I have to show a **full screen ad using mobclix**. I have followed the mobclix site for devlopers. I can show the ad also.

But the real problem is it does not have any cancel option ( so that i can load the next level of the app). Even I cant add the cancel option using layout xml as the **MobClixFullScreenView** is itself  not a view so I cant add this to any other Custom view and it also covers the full screen.

Now I am not getting any clue on how to cancel this fullScreen ad , once it is loaded successfully.

Any idea or help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are actually pushing an update early next week, most likely Monday, that will add a close button for both fullscreen ads and fullscreen backfill.

Comment: what if i want to close ads via code??
In my app i have to show in screen ads for specific time. i.e 10sec after that i have to forcefully close full screen ad via code and have to perform my app task.
is it possible to close full screen ad using code or any alternate solution for above problem.